# modifying http header/parameters in a pcap file

Tags: pcap, tcpreplay, http-parameters, justniffer

Is there any way to add/modify existing http header/request parameter in a pcap file? Any tools out there or do I need to assemble back to HTTP using Justniffer or similar tool and go from there?

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any simple CLI tools or anything like that, but you can do this sorta thing with Scapy: http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/